# How to swizzle methods with identical names (NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName)?

Tags: objective-c, method-swizzling

I am fairly new to method swizzling, and I'd like to use it to troubleshoot a problem I am having that is likely the result of an errant call to NSNotificationCenter. To do this I want to swizzle to log out each call to NSNotificationCenter's postNotification methods. The problem I have is that there are two methods with the same beginning of their name (here are their would-be swizzled implementations):

```
- (void) xxx_postNotificationName:(nonnull NSString *)notiifcationName object:(nullable id) obj {
    [self xxx_postNotificationName:notiifcationName object:obj];
}

- (void) xxx_postNotificationName:(nonnull NSString *)notificatioName object:(nullable id)obj userInfo:(nullable NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [self xxx_postNotificationName:notificatioName object:obj userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

How can I identify these as separate selectors with a call like the following?

```
SEL originalSelector = ...
```

Won't they both have the form?

```
SEL originalSelector = @selector(postNotificationName:)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The names of the methods are `postNotificationName:object:` and `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`, so they are not the same.